# loading a json file to highchart html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I have a Highchart html page that have to load a json file. 
I whant to do that localy and i try to use this to do so

```
 $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {....}
```

Of course date.json is in the same directory and well populated 
but i have this error every time

> Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol scheme

I tried a lot of thing but didn't found what i want.
 i think something simple can fixe it but i can't figure out how to

Answer (score 1):

You should run it in a webserver, and access the JSON object with http:// and not with file://

Comment: yes that work like i said that was easy. I just do a little                            `npm install http-server`

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local) for assistance.

You could use something like requireJS and the text loader plugin to load the local data file.  I have not seen an instance of someone trying to load data with jQuery's getJSON() call from a local source; use a server to host your data, even a local one will do, if you want to use the jQuery method.